# Mercurial: annotate / blame current line number

Tags: mercurial

```
hg annotate -unl aFile
```

Shows:

```
jim 1519:477:     a = 4
bob 1518:468:     b = 5
joe 1496:402:     return a
```

How do I get it to show

```
jim 401:     a = 4
bob 402:     b = 5
joe 403:     return a
```

Where `401, 402, 403` are the **current** line numbers.  Better yet would be something like git has with `git blame -L 401,403 aFile`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To show current line numbers:

```
hg annotate -u aFile | cat -n
```

To also select only a certain range of line numbers:

```
hg annotate -u aFile | cat -n | sed -n 401,403p
```

Comment: Adding this to .bashrc could save some typing: `function hgblame() { hg annotate -u $1 | cat -n | sed -n $2p }`. Maybe colorcat would be nicer..

Comment: Bit of a mouthful, but spot on.  I wonder why they chose not to implement this.  And thanks @xr09 for the bash.

Answer (score 2):

I always use the annotate view in `hg serve` or from TortoiseHg. I find the command line annotate pretty poor since I cannot quickly jump to a parent revision. The hgweb annotate can be seen here:

- https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/annotate/tip/README

It includes (current) line numbers.